# Cleaning up a cache of .net WeakReferences

Tags: .net, caching, garbage-collection, weak-references, finalizer

In my application, I have a `Dictionary<int, WeakReference<Foo>>` to cache `Foo`s read from a file, where the key is the index in the file. Since the `Foo`s are mutable, a cache entry must remain alive as long as any reference to the `Foo` at that index (so that changes are visible to any holders as well as anyone reading fresh from the `Foo` source).

I would like to remove the `Dictionary` entry once the `Foo` is completely unreferenced. My initial idea had the finalizer of `Foo` remove itself from the cache, but this led to inconsistent internal state when a GC was triggered on cache insertion. I'm trying to take to heart the concept that finalizers cannot be used for managed memory, period. So is there any way to do this?

Comment: How about doing nothing, and let the GC and WeakReferences do their stuff?

Comment: The GC will clean up the `Foo`s, but not the `KeyValuePair<int, WeakReference<Foo>>`s in the dictionary.

Comment: I know, but that's a very tiny amount of memory. All of it reclaimed when you close the File/Dictionary pair .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this with a project I'm calling [BackgroundFinalizer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BackgroundFinalizer/) (source on [github](https://github.com/shlevy/BackgroundFinalizer)). Essentially this allows you to define a "finalizer" that is not run during garbage collection and instead is run in the background. So in my particular case here, when the `Foo` is garbage collected a function which removes the entry from the cache is scheduled to run in a worker thread independent of the GC, so we avoid any cases of blocking in a finalizer or inconsistent internal state.

Comment: All finalizers run in the background... This seems no different than just a `~Foo()`

Comment: My description/naming is probably bad, but it's in the background *with respect to the GC*. That is, if it blocks it won't stop collection from continuing, if GC runs while internal state of some object is indeterminate it won't be visible to the finalizer, etc.

Comment: Your `Foo`s must be very flaky... The guidline for finalizers is not to throw and not to block. If you can fix that it would be so much more reliable.

Comment: It's nothing about the `Foo`, it's about the cache. Inserting an element into the cache can trigger a gc, which can run the finalizer on the same thread as the insertion. Unless the dictionary is lock-free, that either means an inconsistent internal state or deadlock.

Comment: _"run the finalizer on the same thread as the insertion."_ No, that won't happen.

Comment: It may not ever run on the same thread, but the insertion may be blocked (in an inconsistent state) until the gc completes, which in this case is essentially the same thing. But I thought that you could run with a single-threaded gc anyway?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me that what you're looking for is a [`ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), where you store `Foo` as your key, instead of your value:

> The ConditionalWeakTable class differs from other
>   collection objects in its management of the object lifetime of keys
>   stored in the collection. Ordinarily, when an object is stored in a
>   collection, its lifetime lasts until it is removed (and there are no
>   additional references to the object) or until the collection object
>   itself is destroyed. However, in the ConditionalWeakTable class, adding a key/value pair to the table does not ensure
>   that the key will persist, even if it can be reached directly from a
>   value stored in the table (for example, if the table contains one key,
>   A, with a value V1, and a second key, B, with a value P2 that contains
>   a reference to A). Instead, **ConditionalWeakTable
>   automatically removes the key/value entry as soon as no other
>   references to a key exist outside the table.**

Comment: I need to be able to look up by int index though.

Comment: Creating a hack could be using a `Dictionary<int, ConditionalWeakTable<Foo, WhatEver>` and then extracting the `Foo` from the conditional table. But that's a but ugly..

Comment: That wouldn't help at all. I want to remove the entry from the dictionary when it's collected.

Comment: @SheaLevy Let me ask you this, why do you care about cleaning up the dictionary? If it's memory you're worried about, `WeakReference` is ~16bytes. Having 500,000 of those would be around 8MB. Are you really worried about that?

Comment: We may end up processing millions or billions of `Foo`s (in a streaming fashion). For now I'm just keeping the entries, but I'd like to do something better if possible.

Comment: @SheaLevy You can always have a dedicated thread pooling the collection every once in a while to cleanup dead objects..

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no way to automatically remove a `Dictionary` entry when the object gets dereferenced, another idea is to remove it yourself as soon as you learn about it, by writing your cache-getting function like that:

```cs
private readonly Dictionary<int,WeakReference<Foo>> _dict;
public bool TryGetItem(int key, out Foo item) {
    if (_dict.TryGetvalue(key, out var wr)) {
        if (wr.TryGetTarget(out item))
            return true;
        else
            // The weak reference is dead. We remove the dictionary entry.
            _dict.Remove(key);
    }
    return false;
}
```